# Title used for pages

Tags: nodes

I have installed Drupal 6.19 and 6.20; in Drupal 6.19, I can see the page title like "site title|page title", but in Drupal 6.20 the page title "site title".

How can I add the node title to the page title in Drupal 6.19?
I didn't use [Page Title](http://drupal.org/project/page_title) in Drupal 6.19, nor did I in Drupal 6.20.

Comment: I am using 6.20 and it uses Page Title | Site title and I have not changed anything. Have you check Site information?

Comment: thank u. i checked but i didnt find anything. what should i find in site information?

Comment: The "Name", by default this should be appearing next to your Page Tile after a pipe. Try changing it see if it makes a difference. Also try a stock theme...

Comment: You should try changing the theme currently used in your website; set another theme as default one.

Answer (score 2):

In the template.php of the theme add the following code.

```
function phptemplate_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $title = $vars['title'];
  $site_name = $vars['site_name'];

  $vars['head_title'] = implode(' - ', array($site_name, $title));
}
```

Verify the `$head_title` variable is present in page.tpl.php.